# Simplify a function with a square root as the numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How would I go about simplifying this:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^4 + 3x^2}}{x}$$

thanks!

Comment: Factor out $x^2$ and use the fact that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2(x^2+3)}}{x}=\frac{|x| \sqrt{x^2+3}}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2}}{x}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2(x^2+3)}}{\sqrt{x^2}} \\ =\sqrt{\frac{x^2(x^2+3)}{x^2}} \\ = \sqrt{x^2+3}$$